# plr.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: postgresql, plr

I have Postgres version 10 installed running under windows 10 enterprise using the pl/r interface. It has been working nicely up till now. Now I get 
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/lib/plr.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
error message. I tried to download  and replace the Pl/r files (both the 64bit and the 32 bit versions), stopped/restarted the service, but it did not help. Any suggestions?

Comment: The Postgres installation location indicates that you are using a 64bit Postgres, so you need to use a 64bit version of PL/r

Comment: Tried it, but the message remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause: Rdotnet needed the 32bit version of R and I changed the path (and forgot all about it). The error message was misleading, because it R had the wrong version, not the plr.dll. (if I copied the 32bit version od the dll it still didn't work). So thanks for trying to help.